# Why SVM with gamma='scale' for RBF kernel works so well?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, scikit-learn, rbf-kernel

The intuitive explanation for the `gamma` parameter of the RBF kernel in SVMs is the following:

> Intuitively, the `gamma` parameter defines how far the influence of a single training example reaches, with low values meaning ‘far’ and high values meaning ‘close’. The `gamma` parameters can be seen as the inverse of the radius of influence of samples selected by the model as support vectors.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html#rbf-svm-parameters

In `sklearn.svm.SVC` the default value of the parameter `gamma` is `'scale'`, i.e. `gamma = 1 / (n_features * X.var())`. What is the explanation for this default choice of `gamma` and why does it work so well (at least for my dataset, I couldn't beat this value with extensive grid-search for `gamma`)?